# How to position (align) chart title to the left with OpenPyXL

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to position (align) the chart title to the top left of a Line Chart.
I cannot really find any information from the docs on how to do this.

`openpyxl.chart.title` has the layout property but I am unsure if that is the property to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The Layout class has to be set with a ManualLayout

```
from openpyxl.chart.layout import Layout, ManualLayout
man_layout = ManualLayout(xMode="edge", yMode="edge", x=0.0, y = 0.0)
line_chart.title.layout = Layout(manualLayout=man_layout)
```